# MVC how to hide @Render

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm doing a browser check and trying to display a warning message if the person is using a browser that is not compatible(IE 8 and less), believe me, there are people using it where i work

The problem i'm having is i cannot seem to hide the @Render of the page

My if statements are all kicking in fine, and i have wrapped the @Render with a div and i'm trying to hide it based on the conditions i get, like so

```
else {
            $("#yourMessage").show();
            $("#content").hide();
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div id="yourMessage" hidden="hidden">Some Message</div>
```

Is there something built in to MVC to stop me from being able to do this?

Comment: Could you be a lot more specific as to what you are doing? MVC as such is only a concept. And HTML could be seen as M or V, but as itself does not imply what could be your point at all.

Comment: i'm not sure i can put this in more simple terms. Im trying to hide the content div, and show the yourMessage div, it will not allow me to hide the content div which contains the @RenderBody()

Comment: A good start would be to name your technology stack. I figured HTML, but that cannot be the whole deal.